# Git: tracking a file with a name that changes

Tags: git

I'm using some proprietary software that is configured with a dozen or so text files stored in a specific directory. The software is relatively well-behaved in dealing with user modifications, it keeps modifications it makes to the files while running in a separate section of each file. But I'd like to track the changes, both ones I make manually and ones made by the software.

Ordinarily, this would be a great use case for Git: make the config directory a Git repo, and it'll identify the changes no matter how they got made. I can look at the diffs, commit changes, experiment with a bunch of changes at once with a branch, roll back, and even use `git bisect` if something goes awry. I can push the repo up to GitHub on one machine and pull it back down to others, and changes made on one can be merged with changes made on another.

The problem is that one of these files *include the username*. So on one site the file is `trey.conf`, on another it's `treyharris.conf`. I need Git to recognize these as the same file.

A symbolic link seems like the obvious choice: rename the file to a static name like `user.conf` and symlink the other names to that file. And that works, for the software's *reading* the config and for manual configuration changes. Unfortunately, the software doesn't respect the symlink when *writing out* changes, and replaces the `trey(harris)?[.]conf` symlink with a plain file.

So far, I've dealt with this just by coming behind every time I want to commit and fixing the situation by moving the username-specific file back to `user.conf` and restoring the symlink. But this is getting more and more annoying as time goes on.

Is there some Git magic I can use to rectify this? I thought maybe filters were the way to go, smudging into `${USER}.conf` and cleaning back into `user.conf`, but I can't figure out how to make that work correctly.

Comment: A file that dynamically generates and is subject to change doesn't sound like a good use case for Git.  Maybe if there was a layer between Git and the file itself instead....but not Git directly.

Comment: Maybe you could use the same username everywhere

Comment: @Makoto You would agree that not for that one tiny thing, this would be a use case for Git, right? It seems like an incredibly silly little detail to make the difference.

Comment: @RC. I'd love to, but it was not by choice. I actually use this software at three sites, two of which have username policies that guarantee I couldn't have the same name on both, even if the company let me change my username at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Git can detect renames itself.  Just leave the name of the file as it is, don't bother with the symlinking.  Run `git add -A .` to add all changes to the index after external changes have been made.  `git status` should now show a "renamed: treyharris.conf -> trey.conf" if the files are still similar enough.  Some git commands need special options to enable rename detection, e.g. `git log` and `git diff` both require the `-M` flag to detect renames.

Comment: You'll also want `-C` to detect copies, I think the OP will have multiple copies of the same file.

Comment: This doesn't quite work; any time a change happens on both sides before merging, you get a merge conflict. If, instead of `git add -A .`, you do a `git mv incorrectname correctname` and commit that before making any other changes, then git handles the merging automatically, but you have to do a move commit every time you pull.

Comment: @Trey: I guess I didn't fully understand your use case then.  Another option would be to simply automate what you are currently doing manually, i.e. add some precommit hook that renames the files if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a symlink, try a hard link.

A symlink can be thought of as a special file which contains another file name to use instead.  It can be overwritten by a real file.

A hard link is where multiple file names all point to the same underlying data.  A hard link looks just like a normal file because it is a normal file; all normal files are hard links.

Try `ln user.conf trey.conf` and `ln user.conf treyharris.conf` and see what happens.

---

Otherwise, you've run into the general problem of trying to use version control as a build and release management tool.  You might be able to hack things to work, but really what you need are build and release scripts.

Comment: Can you suggest a tool that is appropriate for this case, then? As I wrote, I need to track both the changes I make to the configs and the changes the software makes to the configs. I can do my writing somewhere other than the place it's in use, but by definition the software will write where it's in use.

Comment: @Trey Keep `user.conf` in your Git repository. Write a script that watches in-place versions, copies them to `user.conf` when they are changed and notifies you (because you'll probably want to review the changes).

Comment: I thought your answer of using hard links would work but for one thing: you'd need to add `trey.conf` and `treyharris.conf` to the `.gitignore` file. Otherwise, git gets very, very confused as every change is seen in two files. Unfortunately, when git updates `user.conf`, it breaks the hard link.

Comment: A hard link is very unlikely to make a difference in this scenario.  If the program overwriting the file uses the `creat()` system call to open the file, it would work correctly for both hard links and soft links, but it apparently either creates a new file with a different name and `rename()`s it in place, or unlinks the old file before creating a new one (likely the former).  For both these scenarios, neither soft links nor hard links will behave as desired.